# Build MVC6 / ASP.Net 5 project in x86 mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on a new MVC6 / ASP.Net 5 project using VS2015, SP1.
I'm trying to configure ChildCareFamilyProtal project to build in x86 mode.  This is the MVC6 project.  I can select x86 platform from the Platform dropdown.  After I save the configuration and reopen it, the platform is back to "Any CPU"

Note - I have to build in x86 due to existing DLL's that I cannot change.

Below is screen shot of my configuration manager.

[image]

Comment: Check the individual properties for the ChildCareFamilyPortal project. Under Build, there should be something to set what it builds as on its own. That'd be my first guess of where to look. Make sure it is set to only x86 for every permutation of the Configurations.

Comment: There doesn't appear way to select an x86 platform option in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Open properties for ChildCareFamilyPortal, navigate to the Build tab, and select x86 from the Platform target. That should take care of the problem.

Comment: This is not an option that I can select.  The problem seems to revolve around not being able to save a x86 configuration.

Comment: The option doesn't appear on the project properties page, Build tab? What options do show for Platform target?

Comment: I create a new platform using the configuration manager and save.  When I reopen the configuration manager or go to the build tab, "Any CPU" is the only option.

Comment: Are you in project properties for your web project?